# Fluid to particles under newtonian gravity

Tags: newtonian-gravity

How to start with a perfect fluid concept and reach (by approximations through certain mathematically well defined assumptions) to the concept of particle ? Here newtonian gravitation is being assumed. The state equation of matter can be assumed to be that of dust.

**EDIT**

Assume any initial mass distribution $\rho(r,t=0)$ and momentum distribution $p(r,t=o)$ and state equation of dust.

**EDIT 2**

I don't intend to throw away the fluid concept,but still want to arrive at a particle as some form of a mass distribution.One example could be $\rho_p(r,t)$ which has a compact support in r describing a particle.

**EDIT 3**

Assume there are a number of such particles as described in the earlier edit part of the question as $\rho_p(\vec{r}-\vec{r_i},t=0)$ for $i = 1,2,3,...$. distributed arbitrarily in space such that  no two are overlapping. This could be considered as $\rho(r,t=0) = \displaystyle\sum\limits_{i=0}^n \rho_p(\vec{r}-\vec{r_i},t=0)$. Similarily for momentum distibution at $t=0$ as $\vec{p}(r,t=0) = \displaystyle\sum\limits_{i=0}^n \vec{p_p}(\vec{r}-\vec{r_i},t=0)$. What would eventually happen to such a system under its own newtonian gravity. Just out of curiosity what would happen if GR is assumed.

Comment: Can you improve the question by putting your starting assumptions in equation form? It's hard to tell exactly what you mean here.

Comment: @Sklivvz : i have updated the question

Comment: For what it's worth, Newtonian gravity in the case of fluids with mass less than planetary orders of magnitude is more or less negligible.

Comment: I think you should take a look at [Landau Volume 6](http://books.google.com/books?id=v6kNAQAAIAAJ&q=landau+volume+6&dq=landau+volume+6&hl=en&ei=jCT8TNTJBYL6lwfqm_GfBQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CCcQ6AEwAA), and read the section in chapter 1 which describes the difference between the concept of a point particle and a fluid particle.  Keep in mind that a "fluid particle" consists of a very large number of atoms, and the velocity distribution in the NS equation describes the motion of fluid particles, not point particles.

Comment: Under Newtonian Gravity, I believe this system will begin to rotate and condense; and under GR I believe it will form a black hole in the limit of infinite time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you want to get from Gauss' gravitational law to Newton's.

$$ \nabla \cdot \textbf{g} = -4 \pi G \rho$$

Integrating both sides over a volume $V$ enclosing a mass $M$ and having surface $S$.

$$\int_{V} \! \nabla \cdot \textbf{g } \mathrm{d}\textbf{V} = -4 \pi G \int_{V} \! \rho\ \mathrm{d}\textbf{V}$$

$$\int_{V} \! \nabla \cdot \textbf{g } \mathrm{d}\textbf{V} = -4 \pi G M$$

Using the [divergence theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem): $\int_{V} \! \nabla \cdot \textbf{g } \mathrm{d}\textbf{V} = \oint_{\partial{V}}  \textbf{g} \cdot \mathrm{d}\textbf{S}$

$$\oint_{\partial{V}} \! \textbf{g} \cdot \mathrm{d}\textbf{S} = -4\pi GM $$

Assuming that $\textbf{g}$ is constant over $\mathrm{d}\textbf{S}$, and that the force is centripetal we can write 
$$\textbf{g} = g(r){\textbf{e}_r}$$

where $\textbf{e}_r$ are the unit vectors of the acceleration that point towards the center on the surface $S$ and g(r) gives us the magnitude of the acceleration at radius $r$.

Our equation then becomes:

$$g(r)\oint_{\partial{V}} \! \textbf{e}_r \cdot \mathrm{d}\textbf{S} = -4\pi GM $$

$$g(r) 4\pi r^2 = -4\pi GM $$

$$g(r) = -\frac{GM}{r^2} $$

Comment: Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: I'll just add that to get from third to fourth line one needs a [Stokes' theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes%27_theorem).

Comment: Correct, I forgot to mention it.

Comment: @Sklivvz : I don't intend to throw away the fluid concept,but still want to arrive at a particle as some form of a mass distribution.One example could be $\rho_p(r,t)$ which has a compact support in $r$ describing a particle.

Comment: @Rajesh D: you just need an enclosing volume for this derivation to work, which is a weaker condition than the one you describe (i.e. you don't care about $\rho$ as long as it is contained and integrable over a volume.)

Comment: @Sklivvz : I agree with you, but i intended to ask a different question which isn't a derivation for field stength alone. Please see the new edit 3 in question for clarity in explanation.

Comment: @Rajesh D: The notion of a particle in a field theory is always a bit interpretation, I would say. The answer given by Sklivvz is perfectly fine. Further, I would suggest you to look at quantum mechanics and the interpretation of the wave function for further insights.

Comment: @Rajesh D: you don't need to use a perfect fluid representation to determine the dynamics of such system. You can merely use a computer and plug in as many point particles as you can computationally get away with and use Newton. Or, if your particles are way too many, you should use fluid dynamics and simply consider the average properties (such as $\rho$ and $P$). In this case you would have a different starting distribution, without point particles.

Comment: @Sklivvz : But i want this condition not for any practical purpose but for theoretical reasons. I want to preserve the fluid nature of mass and see what would eventually happen. for eample two particles can join to form a single particle or all the particles could join to form a single one or may be something else could happen...the non overlapping is requires only at $t=0$.

Comment: @Rajesh D: The accurate answer is that the problem is: either you can simplify through assumptions or the calculations become really complex really fast - even using Newtonian laws. Example: the vast complexity of the solar system is explained, in large part, without invoking GR. Your problem is no different.

Comment: @Sklivvz : The question is 'What would eventually happen to such a system ?'.....the word 'eventually' i think makes it an answerable question.

Comment: It's notoriously chaotic and has many different endgames, depending on the starting conditions. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-body_problem and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-body_problem